# Curious badge not given even though the requirements are met

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-progress

This is what my problem is, 6/5 showed but badge not given. Is there something beyond the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious)?

> Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record

[image]

Comment: Do you have a positive question record? From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/253560), the formula is `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5`.

Comment: @josilber I think so

Comment: @resueman Answer says update not occurs at the same time. But I think stackoverflow update it really fast.

Comment: @josilber I did not applied that formula, Is this the way stackoverflow give this badge.

Comment: @josliber techincally speaking, that's "sub-50%", not "negative".  I just had to say something nitpicky because I am on Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 14):

No, you're missing the "positive question record requirement".

It even says so in your profile:

[image]

To get a positive question record, we'd need to look [at the actual calculations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399) performed:

- Only questions with a score >= 1 count ("well-received")
- Only days where all questions that were well-received count
- The formula is (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5
- Questions which are downvoted, deleted, and closed count thrice.

With that in mind...

- [You have ten questions that are well-received.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2408913+is%3Aquestion+score%3A1..), and you have [25 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2408913+is%3Aquestion)
- There are no negative questions asked on the same day that would disqualify any well-received questions.
- [You have three negatively scored questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2408913+score%3A..-1)
- [You have two closed questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2408913+closed%3Ayes)
- There are likely some questions that were downvoted (x), closed (y), and deleted(z), which would count against you.

So, that'd make the calculation this:

```
((25 + z) - (3 + x) - (2 + y) - z) / (25 + z) < 0.5
```

This could mean one of two things:

- Either you don't have any deleted questions and the script just needs to play catch-up (in that case, get some popcorn and be patient), or
- You've got a deleted question or two and it's factoring more into this equation than what we mere mortals can see.

Comment: think I don't have any deleted quetions, maybe, actually I'm not rememeber

Comment: it showed 5/5 a long time

Comment: You should be able to check on your questions tab if you have any that were recently deleted.  If there are any that were (and they were downvoted and closed), then that would be the reason why you're not eligible for the badge.

Comment: shows `No deleted recent questions` for me

Comment: Have you deleted any question at any point in time?  You've got a pretty old account.

Comment: @Nishantha you have 8 deleted questions in total (the most recent not since June)

Comment: 2 years and 4 months now. I think I deleted one question. That would be the case.

Comment: @JonClements how can I see that list?

Comment: @Nishantha unfortunately - there's not a convenient way - I can list them for you though if you really wanted though I guess...

Comment: @JonClements I don't remember delete that much of questions. Can you list them if you please?

Comment: @Nishantha [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723207/best-server-side-scripting-language) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146608/how-interface-work-in-java) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145777/understand-how-interface-works-in-java) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23484583/are-semantic-web-techniques-include-artificial-intelligence) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072189/online-php-editor-with-mysql-integration-and-folder-options-like-cloud9)

Comment: @Nishantha [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674017/how-to-customly-retrieve-show-table-data-and-custom-pagination-without-using-d) [7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636353/how-to-save-an-image-file-in-to-a-sql-database-through-fileupload-tool-with-linq) [8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603167/what-are-the-benefits-by-adding-folders-core-references-for-mvc-web-api-when)

Comment: @Makoto Btw, the number of well-received questions does not go into that formula anywhere. The first and last numbers in the equation are for *total questions*. Number of well-received is only looked at for the other requirement. (Just pointing out that you inserted a 10 there.)

Comment: @JonClements Thanx. 3 deleted by me and 5 by community.

Comment: @JonClements  Btw, I think  this numbering 6/5 misleading users.

Comment: @animuson what do you think?

Comment: @animuson:  Thanks for pointing that out...this is probably my least favorite algorithm here since there's at least three unknowns that non-moderators can see, so the math gets strange sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, I'd _really_ like there to at least be a number indicating the final value so people know how close they actually are.