# Inquisitive badge progress does not reflect progress for Curious badge, which I have already earned

Tags: bug, badges

It happened something that looks strange to me, like a bug, but it could also be that I misunderstood how *SO* actually assign those badges.

I earned the badge **Curious** a few days ago, the description of which is:

> Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a
>   positive question record.

Because of that, as far as I've understood, the progress bar for the **Inquisitive** badge should `5/30` for obvious reason. In fact, its description is:

> Ask a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintain a
>   positive question record.

The funny part is that my actual progress for that badge is `4/30` and it doesn't make much sense to me. The issue can be easily verified by visiting my user board (well, maybe by an admin, for I'm not sure those information are publicly available, even though it wouldn't be a problem).

Is there a bug somewhere, I missed something or there is simply another reason I didn't understand yet?

Comment: I'm counting five questions which have a positive score on five distinct days.  I'm not noticing any negatively-scored answers on those specific days.  [There could just be a discrepancy between the display and the script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/255931/175248), but I can't say that with any confidence since [there are so many unknowns for the badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308233/curious-badge-not-given-even-requirements-fullfilled/308234#comment259608_308234) to be accurately rewarded (deleted posts, for one thing).

Comment: It makes sense, but I waited several days before asking the question to see if that discrepancy was filled and nothing happened. It is not a matter of 24h, but over a week of delay. Is it normal?

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. You keep using the word ratio when comparing Curious and Inquisitive when there is no ratio between those two numbers. Inquisitive is just a higher number than Curious. You get it when you reach 30 instead of 5.

Comment: @animuson You are right, 30>5, absolutely. The problem is that I reached 5 (in fact I got the Curious badge), but still I have to make 26 questions for the Inquisitive badge... Well, as far as I know, 30-5=25 != 26!! Is it perfectly normal?

Comment: Are you saying that the badge tracker is saying your progress towards Inquisitive is at 4?

Comment: Yeah, `4/30` instead of `5/30` since over a week ago. How long does it take to update? Usually it's faster.

Comment: The tracker is correct. After you received the badge, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683083/unordered-map-operator-and-shared-ptr) was downvoted and no longer counts as a well-received question since it is now zero-scored. So now you only have 4. We just don't retract already-earned badges if you fall below the requirements later.

Comment: @animuson You are right!! Thank you, really appreciated. Only a note: can I suggest you not to use the word *we* the way you used it in the comment? For the first time since I signed in SO, I didn't feel part of a family because of that comment... :-( ... Not a criticism, do not misunderstand, but it has been weird.

Comment: @skypjack Unless your profile needs updating, you are not part of *that* family: animuson is a Stack Exchange employee, and by “we” he means Stack Exchange. But even if “we” had been used to mean SO users: you're an SO user too. “We” does not exclude the person one is talking to.

Comment: It was my feel, again, not a criticism. Thanks for the clarification anyway. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, but just a quirk of the system.

[animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311311/curious-and-inquisitive-badges-mistake#comment276939_311311) put it best in the comments:

> The tracker is correct. After you received the badge, this question was downvoted and no longer counts as a well-received question since it is now zero-scored. So now you only have 4. We just don't retract already-earned badges if you fall below the requirements later.

So yes, your progress for the Curious badge did show 5/5.  You did receive the badge, at which time, the progress for the Inquisitive would have shown 5/30.  But since you received a downvote on one of your eligible questions, it no longer counts towards the badge.  So that explains why your Inquisitive progress is now showing 4/30.

And since Stack Overflow does not remove *most* badges once earned, you retained your Curious badge despite no longer being eligible.