# Curious (need positive question record)

Tags: support, badges

Why did I not get the [Curious badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399) even though I have the following question records?

```
27 questions Score > 0
6 questions Closed
4 questions score <= 0
0 question deleted
Total questions is 31
```

To get this badge I need to *"ask a well-received question on five separate days, and maintained a positive question record"*.

I have at least five questions that are well received on five separate days, but it shows me that I do not get a positive question record. Why?

I checked this question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262814/whats-the-meaning-of-well-received-question-and-of-maintaining-a-question), and I get this equation:

```
(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted) / total questions >= 0.5
```

According to this, I get 0.67 which is more than 0.5?

```
(31-4-6-0)/31 = 0.67 > 0.5
```

Any explanation to this?

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions?  They may be hidden from you (due to you having less than 10K rep) so only a mod could fill that detail in.

Comment: no, I do not have

Comment: You have the peer pressure badge, which is for deleting a post with score -3 or lower. Was that an answer?

Comment: You also have at least one deleted question, that you got the tumbleweed badge for and has since presumably been cleaned up by the automatic scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000167/zbar-code-and-uiimage-resource

Comment: Note that down voted deleted questions count against you twice.

Comment: @TZHX Thanks, but how can I know the number of total deleted question that I have? I thought they are 0.

Comment: Do you remember deleting an answer? In your rep history, with 'show removed posts' checked on, can you see any posts removed?

Comment: @HazemAbdullah just to note: You have 11 deleted questions of which 5 are negatively scored and two are closed - if my maths is right - that means your ratio is a third...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm counting about 23 or so days (without any deletions) which count towards the badge.  That is to say, these dates count against you having a day in which all questions are well received, due to a single question being downvoted or closed:

- 13 Dec 15
- 14 April 15
- 26 March 15
- 21 Jan 14
- 20 Jan 14
- 18 Jan 14
- 15 Jan 14

So you have to remove them from the sum of eligible questions *outright*.

If we're generous and say that the question deleted for your Tumbleweed badge did *not* impact your standings, then your calculations become thus:

`(23-4-6)/31 ~ 0.42`

...which would be *less* than the threshold needed.

This is [my least favorite calculation to do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308233/curious-badge-not-given-even-requirements-fullfilled/308234#comment259608_308234) since there are unknowns to mere mortals, but at a glance, this is what I'm seeing.